# gwt - history - how to "keep" UI state

Tags: gwt, gwt-history

I tried the [example](http://www.javabeat.net/history-management-in-gwt/) which is showing how to get data from history to re-generate UI; The thing I see mostly in all "history usage" examples are related to UI re-generation only so it is none-static way...

But what about "each UI state may have its unique url something like JSF does with flows"? For example I have app url like a

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyApp.html
```

the app default UI contains main menu which is helping to navigate through my test catalog; I tried to make possible keep the UI dynamics in history by building url in this way

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyApp.html#menu_testcategory_page1
```

but when I click internet browser "refresh" button the url keeps the same as `http://localhost:8080/myapp/MyApp.html#menu_testcategory_page1` but the UI comes back to its default state :(

So my question is

is there an optimal way in pure gwt to stay in the same UI state even after browser's refresh button is clicked (I mean the unload/load window events occur)?

thanks

P.S. gwt 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement Activities and Places pattern: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

I am using it for 3 years, and it works very well.

Note, however, that when you reload a page, you lose all of your state, data, etc. If you need to preserve some of it, you can use a combination of a Place (#page1) and a token that tells the corresponding Activity the state of the View representing this Place, i.e. (#page1:item=5).

Comment: Does it help to "keep" UI and not to return into its default state even after refresh is clicked or it is dedicated to re-generate UI by using history flags ? Please give more details.

Comment: You cannot keep anything when you reload a page - the browser destroys all UI. It does not matter what you use - GWT or something else. You can only tell the code through a URL where a user was, and provide additional details through a token, but your code will have to recreate the UI again after the page reloads.

Comment: I mean UI "cache" ... Is there a way to cache UI current state or there is no way except regenerating UI every gwt app re-load? The thing is - it is very inconvenient because in case of catalog navigation re-generating each catalog page, moreover, if regenerating all graphics for (catalog page N) from scratch for example there is RPC needed :(

Comment: I once built an app where a page is refreshed 60 times per second, and even smartphone browsers had no problem doing it 3 years ago. Getting data from a server is a different story, but here you can use caching on the server side for fast response. You can also store up to 5MB in a local storage of modern browsers, and then access this data when a page reloads.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just forgot to call

```
History.fireCurrentHistoryState();
```

from your entry point.